# Cannot succes do as in tutorial of flask-peewee

Tags: flask, peewee

I learning using [flask-peewee](http://flask-peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). As in tutorial [there](http://flask-peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started.html#creating-a-simple-model), i apply this script (app.py):

```
import datetime
from flask import Flask
from flask_peewee.auth import Auth
from flask_peewee.db import Database
from peewee import *
from flask_peewee.admin import Admin



# configure our database
DATABASE = {
    'name': 'exampleappusi.db',
    'engine': 'peewee.SqliteDatabase',
}
DEBUG = True
SECRET_KEY = 'ssshhhh'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

# instantiate the db wrapper
db = Database(app)


class Note(db.Model):
    message = TextField()
    created = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)


# create an Auth object for use with our flask app and database wrapper
auth = Auth(app, db)

admin = Admin(app, auth)
admin.register(Note)

admin.setup()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    auth.User.create_table(fail_silently=True)
    Note.create_table(fail_silently=True)

    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

And until this part:

> We now have a functioning admin site! Of course, we’ll need a user log in with, so open up an interactive python shell in the directory alongside the app and run the following:

As an in the tutorial, we do in python shell (I understand that we do this following to adding user and pass as manual way):

```
>> from auth import User
>> admin = User(username='admin', admin=True, active=True)
>> admin.set_password('admin')
>> admin.save()
```

The problem is i get error when execute ">> from auth import User", which mean No module named auth. Sure, in this case we need auth.py , but what the auth.py should be ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your module is named `app` so you should import `auth` there.

```
>> from app import auth
>> User = auth.User
>> admin = User(username='admin', admin=True, active=True)
>> admin.set_password('admin')
>> admin.save()
```

Comment: This is solved. But with little modification, because still get error that "user.mail may not be NULL". So with this command, work great. 


`>> admin = User(username='admin', email='admin@myadminmail.com', admin=True, active=True)`


Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a auth.py file:

**auth.py (same directory as app.py)**

```
from flask_peewee.auth import Auth
from app import app, db

auth = Auth(app, db)
```

You will also need a models.py to create a User:

https://github.com/coleifer/flask-peewee/blob/master/example/models.py